# Display Presence in Staff Directory made with Search REST API

Tags: 2013, presence-indication

I've made a custom staff directory using the Search REST API (Local People Results). This works well, but I can't figure out how to show a user's presence (Available, Busy, Away etc).

I don't think there's a REST API to get presence, how can I accomplish this?